# HTML5 drag and drop for inputs

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, textinput

I'm experimenting with HTML5, making html elements draggable. It worked on button, but not on text input, the same exact code. Any reason for this? It calls the dragstart hadnler, but right after it calls the dragend handler as well and it doesn't even begin The button itself only works on Chrome, but the input type text doesn't work at all.

(The one working is a button element, not a input type button or submit)

Comment: Try putting your draggable attribute on a label instead of the input field itself. `<label draggable='true'>Username<br/><input type='text' size='30'></label>`  Allegedly you can tag any element as draggable, but I've found that browsers vary a lot and implementations to be spotty.

Comment: Hmmm, but I wanted to drag the actual input, a labelless one :/

Comment: Anything you want to do is going to be restricted by what the browser supports, and browsers aren't fully up to speed with draggable.  To get good compatibility, I wouldn't be surprised if you need to wrap your input tag inside something else: a label, a div, something...

Comment: I had wrapped with a div and it didn't work. Went with jQuery-ui's drag&drop, much less code and it works all around with a few tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

DnD isnt working for buttons on firefox. You can get it to work on textinput, label in firefox but it won't work in chrome.